# Route planner for moped in Norway and Sweden?

Tags: driving, routes, sweden, norway, scooters

When I travel by car or bicycle, I use Google Maps to plan the route and to get some rough idea in advance of how long the journey might take.

However, when I travel by moped, I face two problems:

1. There are roads (two-lane expressways, and controlled-access highways) that mopeds (50 cc) are not allowed on here. Chosing car mode will suggest those. Chosing bicycle mode will suggest roads that mopeds are *not* allowed on, such as pedestrian/forest roads, etc.
2. Since mopeds here only run at 45 km/h, the estimated time of the journey will not be accurate with Google Maps, whether I chose bicycle or car.

Regarding 1, I know that Google Maps has an *avoid highways* function. Will this mean the route will work for mopeds in Norway and Sweden? When I use Google Maps in Norwegian, the feature is called *unngå motorveier*. Motorveier means controlled-access highways. However, in Norway we also have something called motortrafikkvei, which means two-lane expressway. Mopeds are not allowed on those either.

Is there a route planner, similar to Google Maps, that has a speficic "moped mode", in the same way that Google Maps has a "bicycle mode"?

Is there any way to get (at least roughly) accurate time estimates from Google Maps when on a moped?

I have tried searching the web for this, but I have not found satisfactory results.

Comment: Selecting 'avoid highways/unngå motorveier' in Google Maps, does not avoid so called motortrafikkveier. FWIW, the Google Maps bicycle planner is itself not particularly reliable in Norway. You may be routed onto highways or through tunnels, where you are not allowed to bicycle and you may be routed onto very poor 'roads', which are not more than walkable hiking paths, where you at least can't drive with a regular road bike.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Thanks for this useful information.

Comment: How long is the journey?

Comment: @JoelDamien I'm asking in general, not about any particular route.

Comment: Bearing in mind that Norway/Sweden are absolutely HUGE, moped travel can be difficult.  Given their immense size, you may have to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there are not so much options for you. However, you can start with some routes on [this site](http://www.mopedmap.net/en/route/225254-voss-elvestern/#/z8/60.5086392,7.130127/terrain) to see some basic trips made by other people. As all the social networks, the linked one eventually will be good enough, but for now it's really only a start point. Other similar site is [this one](https://www.plotaroute.com/route/85734), yet it also contain only routes made by other people, not a navigation engine.

[Wikivoyage mentions](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Driving_in_Norway) the [National tourist routes](http://www.nasjonaleturistveger.no/en) created by Norway government, such list may help in planning too. Didn't find any suitable results for Sweden at all - most planning sites use Google as a route engine.